# path variable binding returns duplicate node matches - why?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
CREATE(:ENTRY {name:"alpha"})-[:REL]->(:ENTRY {name:"beta"})<-[:REL]-(:ENTRY {name:"gamma"})
```

Now, let's try and have the same graph elements returned as a path:

```
MATCH p=(:ENTRY {name:"alpha"})-[:REL]->(:ENTRY {name:"beta"})<-[:REL]-(:ENTRY {name:"gamma"})
RETURN p
```

We'll see two 'betas' in the Table view:

{
  "name": "beta"
}
,

{
  "name": "beta"
}

But why?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. What does the first query return? What are the actual full results of the second query? If you could recreate the issue and share via http://console.neo4j.org, that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: same here. can't reproduce the issue. Can't see 2 "betas" in my output.

Comment: Just a misinterpretation of results on my part - see accepted answer. It does _look_ like two betas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you started from an empty database, this is probably just some confusion about what is shown in the tabular result when you return a path.

You're going to see a representation of relationships connecting nodes, and each relationship representation consists of 3 parts: start node (according to the path ordering, not necessary the start node with respect to relationship direction), properties of the relationship, then the end node.

So to break it down:

rel1 data, rel2 data

which translates to:

rel1 start, rel1 props, rel1 end, rel2 start, rel2 props, rel2 end

which translates to:

alpha node props, rel1 props, beta node props, beta node props, rel2 props, gamma node props

The properties of the relationships in your pattern are empty, that explains the empty maps. Note that for a relationship chain, the node at the end of the previous relationship is the same node at the start of the next relationship. That's why you're seeing beta come up twice: